# Why is my flutter code generation using `build_runner` and `source_gen` not creating output files?

Tags: flutter, dart, build, code-generation, build-runner

I am trying to create a code generation package within Flutter using the `build_runner` and `source_gen` packages. I've looked over numerous examples but cannot seem to find what is preventing my output files from being created. I know it's probably something stupid, but I've been trying for days and cannot seem to find the problem.

So far, I've got the following directory structure:

```
─┬ fletch
 ├── fletch_annotations
 ├── fletch_example
 └── fletch_generator
```

`fletch_annotations` has annotation classes like the following:

##### `package:fletch_annotations/src/model/annotation/column.dart`

```dart
import 'package:fletch_annotations/src/model/enum/enum.dart';

class Column {
  final FletchDataType dataType;
  final bool isNullable;
  final OnConflictAction onConflictAction;
  final OnDeleteAction onDeleteAction;
  final OnUpdateAction onUpdateAction;
  final bool isUnique;
  final String? columnName;
  final dynamic defaultValue;
  final String? check;

  const Column({
    required this.dataType,
    required this.isNullable,
    this.onConflictAction = OnConflictAction.abort,
    this.onDeleteAction = OnDeleteAction.setDefault,
    this.onUpdateAction = OnUpdateAction.setDefault,
    this.isUnique = false,
    this.columnName,
    this.defaultValue,
    this.check,
  });
}
```

In `fletch_generator`, I have the following `pubspec.yaml` file:

##### `fletch_generator/pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: fletch_generator
description: A new Flutter package project.
version: 0.0.1
homepage: https://example.com #! TODO: Replace this

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  analyzer: ^5.3.1
  build: ^2.3.1
  collection: ^1.17.0
  fletch_annotations:
    path: ../fletch_annotations
  source_gen: ^1.2.6

dev_dependencies:
  build_config: ^1.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  build_test: ^2.1.5
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  test: ^1.22.1
```

`fletch_generator` has corresponding model classes:

##### `package:fletch_generator/src/model/column.dart`

```dart
import 'package:fletch_annotations/fletch_annotations.dart';

class Column {
  final FletchDataType dataType;
  final bool isNullable;
  final OnConflictAction onConflictAction;
  final OnDeleteAction onDeleteAction;
  final OnUpdateAction onUpdateAction;
  final bool isUnique;
  final String? columnName;
  final dynamic defaultValue;
  final String? check;

  Column({
    required this.dataType,
    required this.isNullable,
    this.onConflictAction = OnConflictAction.abort,
    this.onDeleteAction = OnDeleteAction.setDefault,
    this.onUpdateAction = OnUpdateAction.setDefault,
    this.isUnique = false,
    this.columnName,
    this.defaultValue,
    this.check,
  });

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Column &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          dataType == other.dataType &&
          isNullable == other.isNullable &&
          onConflictAction == other.onConflictAction &&
          onDeleteAction == other.onDeleteAction &&
          onUpdateAction == other.onUpdateAction &&
          isUnique == other.isUnique &&
          columnName == other.columnName &&
          defaultValue == other.defaultValue &&
          check == other.check;

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return Object.hash(dataType, columnName, defaultValue, check);
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Column('
        'dataType: $dataType, '
        'isNullable: $isNullable ,'
        'onConflictAction: $onConflictAction ,'
        'onDeleteAction: $onDeleteAction ,'
        'onUpdateAction: $onUpdateAction ,'
        'isUnique: $isUnique ,'
        'columnName: $columnName, '
        'defaultValue: $defaultValue, '
        'check: $check'
        ')';
  }
}
```

My `build.yaml` file in `fletch_generator`:

##### `fletch_generator/build.yaml`

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      fletch_generator:
        enabled: true
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        enabled: true
        options:
          ignore_for_file:
            - lines_longer_than_80_chars
            - lint_alpha
            - lint_beta
          build_extensions: '"{{dir}}/entity/{{file}}.dart": "{{dir}}/dao/{{file}}.g.dart"'

builders:
  fletch_generator:
    import: "package:fletch_generator/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["fletchBuilder"]
    build_extensions: { ".dart": [".fletch.g.part"] }
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_to: cache
    applies_builders: ["source_gen|combining_builder"]
```

`build.dart`, also in `fletch_generator` (in the `lib` directory):

##### `package:fletch_generator/build.dart`

```dart
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:fletch_generator/src/generator/column.dart';
import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';

Builder fletchBuilder(final BuilderOptions _) =>
    SharedPartBuilder([ColumnGenerator()], 'fletch');
```

And finally, the `fletch_generator` definition for `ColumnGenerator`:

##### `package:fletch_generator/src/generator/column.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:analyzer/dart/element/element.dart';
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:fletch_annotations/fletch_annotations.dart' as annotations;
import 'package:source_gen/source_gen.dart';

class ColumnGenerator extends GeneratorForAnnotation<annotations.Column> {
  @override
  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
    Element element,
    ConstantReader annotation,
    BuildStep buildStep,
  ) {
    return '// ColumnProcessor works!';
  }
}
```

In `fletch_example`, I have a `sample_class` that utilizes the `Column` annotation:

##### `package:fletch_example/src/model/entity/sample_class.dart

```dart
import 'package:fletch_annotations/fletch_annotations.dart';

part '../dao/sample_class.g.dart';

class SampleClass {
  @Column(
    dataType: FletchDataType.bigInt,
    isNullable: false,
  )
  final int? sampleClassIndex;

  SampleClass({
    this.sampleClassIndex,
  });
}
```

As well as the appropriate dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` file for `fletch_example`:

```yaml
name: fletch_example
description: A starting point for Dart libraries or applications.
version: 1.0.0
# homepage: https://www.example.com

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.4 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  fletch_annotations:
    path: ../fletch_annotations

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  fletch_generator:
    path: ../fletch_generator
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  lints: ^2.0.0
  test: ^1.16.0
```

In my `fletch_example` directory, I run the following commands:

```bash
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This generates the following console output:

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 525ms

[INFO] Precompiling build script......
[INFO] Precompiling build script... completed, took 9.5s

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.3s

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 1ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Generating SDK summary...
[INFO] 2.8s elapsed, 0/1 actions completed.
[INFO] 5.3s elapsed, 0/1 actions completed.
[INFO] Generating SDK summary completed, took 6.2s

[INFO] Running build completed, took 6.3s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 40ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 6.4s with 0 outputs (2 actions)
```

It also creates the following `fletch_example/.dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart` file:

```dart
// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
// ignore_for_file: no_leading_underscores_for_library_prefixes
import 'package:build_runner_core/build_runner_core.dart' as _i1;
import 'package:fletch_generator/builder.dart' as _i2;
import 'package:source_gen/builder.dart' as _i3;
import 'dart:isolate' as _i4;
import 'package:build_runner/build_runner.dart' as _i5;
import 'dart:io' as _i6;

final _builders = <_i1.BuilderApplication>[
  _i1.apply(
    r'fletch_generator:fletch_generator',
    [_i2.fletchBuilder],
    _i1.toDependentsOf(r'fletch_generator'),
    hideOutput: true,
    appliesBuilders: const [r'source_gen:combining_builder'],
  ),
  _i1.apply(
    r'source_gen:combining_builder',
    [_i3.combiningBuilder],
    _i1.toNoneByDefault(),
    hideOutput: false,
    appliesBuilders: const [r'source_gen:part_cleanup'],
  ),
  _i1.applyPostProcess(
    r'source_gen:part_cleanup',
    _i3.partCleanup,
  ),
];
void main(
  List<String> args, [
  _i4.SendPort? sendPort,
]) async {
  var result = await _i5.run(
    args,
    _builders,
  );
  sendPort?.send(result);
  _i6.exitCode = result;
}
```

My expectation is that a `fletch_example/lib/src/model/dao/sample_class.g.dart` file would be created containing the following:

```dart
// ColumnProcessor works!
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be so, incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `GeneratorForAnnotation` only runs for top-level elements (like classes or top-level fields or methods) in a library. In your example, the `@Column` annotation is added to an instance member which does not trigger the generator.

If you can, the easiest way to fix this would be to exceptionally change your generator so that classes with `@Column` annotations on their fields also need an annotation on the class declaration.

Alternatively, you could use something like this to respect column annotations in class members as well:

```dart
class ColumnGenerator extends Generator {
  static const _checker = TypeChecker.fromRuntime(annotations.Column);

  @override
  Future<String> generate(LibraryReader library, BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final values = <String>{};

    for (final classMember in library.classes) {
      for (final child in classMember.children) {
        final annotation = _checker.firstAnnotationOf(child);

        if (annotation != null) {
          values.add(await generateForAnnotatedElement(
              child, ConstantReader(annotation), buildStep));
        }
      }
    }

    return values.join('\n\n');
  }

  FutureOr<String> generateForAnnotatedElement(
    Element element,
    ConstantReader annotation,
    BuildStep buildStep,
  ) {
    return '// ColumnProcessor works!';
  }
}
```

Comment: This works out perfectly, thank you! It's worth noting (for anyone else that needs this) that I had to also add an annotation to the `SampleClass` class. in order for the `Column` annotation to be hit.  The final `SampleClass` file now looks like this:

```dart
import 'package:fletch_annotations/fletch_annotations.dart';

part '../dao/sample_class.g.dart';

@Table()
class SampleClass {
  @Column(
    dataType: FletchDataType.bigInt,
    isNullable: false,
  )
  final int? sampleClassIndex;

  SampleClass({
    this.sampleClassIndex,
  });
}
```

Comment: gonna try to ride off the coat tails of this question - do you see any reason why my output files are not respecting the `build_extensions` value that should put them into a `dao` directory?

Thank you for the original answer!

Comment: if you're the same person responsible for the Drift package, I just want to toss out that what you have done with it is amazing!